# Can CDN distribution of assets be combined with HTML5 cache manifest in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cache-manifest, asset-sync

In a Rails 3.2 app I'm using asset_sync to host my assets on S3, and Cloudfront to distribute these assets, accessible via 4 CNAME'd URLs. It has been a good way of increasing the app's performance and reducing load on the server.

I'm now beginning to explore offline capabilities and HTML5 cache manifest. Obviously the cache manifest can be used to serve the static assets to repeat visitors.

I have two questions:

1. Can these two approaches be used together? i.e., the first time a
   user visits the app, assets are downloaded from the cloudfront CDN.
   Thereafter, assets are served from the cache manifest. There appear
   to be conflicting reports across the internet as to whether the
   manifest file and assets need to be on the same sub-domain. My app
   is at http://app.example.com, whereas my assets are at
   http://asset0.example.com, http://asset1.example.com, etc.
2. Secondly, how should I handle the unique ID applied to assets? For
   example, assets have names such as
   http://asset1.example.com/assets/application-hdggajdjd7672h12bsud8.js.
   Do I need to handle these random strings to ensure assets are
   properly cached, or are these strings created when updates are
   pushed to the server and assets precompiled, hence will remain
   static unless changes are made to the files.